# How can I make a field of "Content: Type" visible to users who do not have the "Administer content types" permission?

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to create a view which shows new posts of certain content types, including the name of the content type. So, e.g., "New How To: Displaying Content Type Fields in Views". Here are the fields:

- Content: Title [hidden]
- Content: Type [hidden]
- Global: Custom Text
- Content: Authored on

The "Global: Custom Text" field is a combination of the first two fields as "New {{ type }}: {{ title }}". The issue I have is this: The "Type" field appears blank for anonymous users unless I grant them the "Administer content types" permission. This is not an acceptable solution.

Is there a clean way to display this for anonymous users? Maybe a permission I'm missing? Relatedly, is there any danger in allowing users to see this?

I'm working with Drupal 8.0.0-beta14 (the latest at the time of this question). The code for the exported view is below if it helps.

```
uuid: 48ef9d3a-8278-4bc5-b13e-62eec03bad09
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - node.type.blog_post
    - node.type.how_to
  module:
    - node
    - user
id: news_items
label: 'News Items'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: full
        options:
          items_per_page: 4
          offset: 0
          id: 0
          total_pages: null
          tags:
            previous: '<<'
            next: '>>'
            first: '|<'
            last: '>|'
          expose:
            items_per_page: false
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
          quantity: 3
      style:
        type: html_list
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          row_class: list-group-item
          default_row_class: true
          type: ul
          wrapper_class: ''
          class: list-group
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          plugin_id: field
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: entity_reference_label
          settings:
            link: false
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: field
        nothing:
          id: nothing
          table: views
          field: nothing
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: true
            text: 'New {{ type }}: {{ title }}'
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: false
          plugin_id: custom
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          date_format: custom
          custom_date_format: 'Y-M-d g:i:s A'
          timezone: America/Toronto
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: date
      filters:
        status:
          value: true
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
          group: 1
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: in
          value:
            blog_post: blog_post
            how_to: how_to
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
      sorts:
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          order: DESC
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: date
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          granularity: second
      title: 'News Items'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
      css_class: ''
      use_ajax: true
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url.query_args
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      cacheable: false
  block_1:
    display_plugin: block
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url.query_args
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      cacheable: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a field permission on the type field that prevents view access.

Not quite sure where that happens, actually, that would be in `NodeAccessControlHandler::checkFieldAccess()`, as you can see, that for example limits edit access on certain fields, but there's nothing about type, so that *should* be editable.

Ah.. maybe the field checks view access of the referenced entity, and node types aren't viewable by anonymous users, so it doesn't display it.

We have similar problems with e.g. referenced users, since Drupal doesn't have a generic concept of a "view label" access.

You could try to open a core issue and in NodeTypeAccessControlHandler::checkAccess(), allow view access if you have the access content permission or so, but it's tricky.. since that will e.g. also allow access to all values in it (like the settings for it), in case there is a generic check for it (e.g. REST).